# Trying to eliminate cudaDeviceSynchronize() in conjugate gradient kernel

Tags: c, cuda, parallel-processing, gpu, gpgpu

I am implementing Conjugate Gradient Solver on TegraK1 board having unified memory. The problem I am facing is that in the loop I have to do cudaDeviceSynchronize(); two times to update the variables and that is hurting my performance by many times as compared to TI Keystone-II which although has less computational power but I am using only Naive code to parallel compute the data. I am using CUDA version - 6.0.

```
....    
double *A, *b, *x, *x1, *r, *d, *q, deltaNew, deltaFirst, Alpha, deltaOld, Beta; // data for init processing

double *temp, *temp1, Alpha1;

b = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double)*N*1); // b original
x1 = (double *) malloc(sizeof(double)*N*1); // x1 

checkCudaErrors(cudaMallocManaged(&A, sizeof(double)*N*N)); // A original 
checkCudaErrors(cudaMallocManaged(&x, sizeof(double)*N*1)); // x original
checkCudaErrors(cudaMallocManaged(&r, sizeof(double)*N*1)); // r original 
checkCudaErrors(cudaMallocManaged(&d, sizeof(double)*N*1)); // d original
checkCudaErrors(cudaMallocManaged(&q, sizeof(double)*N*1)); // q original
checkCudaErrors(cudaMallocManaged(&temp, sizeof(double)*1*1)); //  temp of d'*q for temporary storage
checkCudaErrors(cudaMallocManaged(&temp1, sizeof(double)*1*1)); //  temp1 of r'*r for temporary storage

fprintf(stderr, "\nIntializing data\n");
// Intializing all the data
setup_data(&A[0], &b[0], &x[0], &r[0], &d[0], &deltaNew, &deltaFirst);

// Get handle to the CUBLAS context 
cublasHandle_t cublasHandle = 0;
cublasCreate(&cublasHandle);
fprintf(stderr, "\nData setup done.. Starting..\n");    
startTime_GPU = omp_get_wtime();

while(deltaNew > (EPSI)*deltaFirst)
{
    // cublasSgemm(handle, op, op, colof2, rowof1, colof1, scalar1, mat2, colof2, mat1, colof1, scalar2, result, colof2 );
    cublasDgemm(cublasHandle, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_N, 1, N, N, &alpha, d, 1, A, N, &beta, q, 1);        // q = A * d   
    cublasDgemm(cublasHandle, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_N, 1, 1, N, &alpha, q, 1, d, N, &beta, temp, 1);        // alpha = deltaNew/(d' * q);

    cudaDeviceSynchronize(); // POSSIBLY ELIMINATE THIS
    Alpha = deltaNew/temp[0]; // alpha = deltaNew/(d' * q);
    Alpha1 = (-1)*Alpha;   

    // cublasSaxpy(handle, N, scalar, scaledinput, stride1, inout, stride2);
    cublasDaxpy(cublasHandle, N, &Alpha, d, 1, x, 1); // x = x + alpha * d  
    cublasDaxpy(cublasHandle, N, &Alpha1, q, 1, r, 1); // r = r - alpha * q

    deltaOld = deltaNew; // deltaOld = deltaNew  

    cublasDgemm(cublasHandle, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_N, 1, 1, N, &alpha, r, 1, r, N, &beta, temp1, 1);        // deltaNew = r' * r

    cudaDeviceSynchronize(); // POSSIBLY ELIMINATE THIS
    deltaNew = temp1[0];
    Beta = deltaNew/deltaOld; // beta = deltaNew/deltaOld
    cublasDgeam(cublasHandle, CUBLAS_OP_N, CUBLAS_OP_N, 1, N, &alpha, r, 1, &Beta, d, 1, d, 1); // d = r + beta * d
}

endTime_GPU = omp_get_wtime();
...
...
```

Can anyone suggest any improvements or enhancements which i can use to eliminate those or reduce and thus gain performance.

Comment: The obvious optimisation would be to not use managed memory in the first place. That is probably the underlying performance problem.

Comment: I have to use managed memory i think because it's Unified Memory and using normal malloc doesn't work.

Comment: Obviously normal malloc doesn't work. But if you explicitly allocated and kept most of the matrices and vectors in device memory and explicitly manage the transfers from host to device, you might fund the performance is better

Comment: How come you have 3 matrix-matrix multiplications (``cublasDgemm``) in conjugate gradient method? Also I guess you want matrix-vector multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kernel launches have *always* been asynchronous in CUDA (even in CUDA 1.0). At that time, explicit memcpy's were required to and from device memory in order for CUDA kernels to operate. The CPU/GPU synchronization was hidden because the device->host memcpy would implicitly enforce an ordering: the device->host memcpy couldn't start until after the kernel had completed.

When the CPU and GPU have mapped the same memory, the synchronization must be done more explicitly.  Without your `cudaDeviceSynchronize()`, your CPU code might read output from the DGEMM before the GPU has written it. Managed memory implements a lot of implicit policy behind kernel launches and CPU/GPU synchronization events such as `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` in an effort to make programming easier.

The way to get CPU/GPU concurrency and still synchronize properly is by multi-buffering and affiliating a CUDA event with each buffer.  Call `cudaEventRecord()` after each DGEMM and call `cudaEventWait()` on that event before consuming the result.

talonmies already said it, but it bears repeating: If you want good performance, you may have to abandon managed memory.